# What would produce this "hamburger" corruption on images?

Tags: noise, image-processing, compression, jpeg

I have an image that has gone through an unknown number of jpeg and webp conversions (at least one but more likely 2+). Currently this image is a JPEG and contains corruptions in single color or mild gradient backgrounds. What could cause this?

[image: hmbrgr]

Comment: Are you certain that that pattern is not present in the original image?

Comment: I suspect that the corruption is there in the original image, but that conversions back-and-forth exacerbate the issue and make the color jump in the palette table.

Comment: I suspect you're both correct. Thanks for confirming. Getting ahold of original

Comment: Here's another set of photos, before corruption and after:
http://take.ms/bfKuX

Comment: SE.DSP wishes you a happy new year 2017, with a kind reminding signal that your question or its answers may require some action (update, votes, acceptance, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

JPEG projects $8\times 8$ blocks of images onto $64$ 2D cosine patterns:

[image]

The one in column $1$ and row $5$, once quantized, may look like your hamburger. Luminance and chroma components may get different subsampling patterns. I suspect that the low varying background is nearly horizontal, and due to the different processing steps, it ends up with a mid-frequency non-zero component. My main issue is its $10\times 10$ apparent size. Apparently, WebP also does some prediction on blocks.

You might be interested in compression forencics, that try to recover the history of compression. For JPEG, [JPEG CHEst (JPEG Compression History Estimation for Color Images)](http://dsp.rice.edu/software/jpeg-chest) does the job, based on paper [JPEG Compression History Estimation
for Color Images](http://signal.ece.utexas.edu/~queiroz/papers/neelsh-journal.pdf).